# return true if the column which have the same ProductID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have table name stock in which i have  5 column name id `productId` `stockIn` `stockOut` And `VoucherType` ..

i want to check the if `productId=1` and `voucherType=1` that count all the column in `stockIn` with the same `ProductId` and Sum All the value in `stockIn` then also count in `stockout` with same product id and sum if the `stockIn` sum is greater then `stockOut` that return true...

```
id ' productid ' stockin 'stockout 'VoucherType

-----------------------------------------
1  |    1      |   5     | 0      |   1
2  |    1      |   5     | 0      |   1   
3  |    1      |   5     | 0      |   1  
4  |    2      |   5     | 0      |   1  
5  |    2      |   0     | 10     |   2   
6  |    1      |   0     | 2      |   2 
7  |    2      |   0     | 3      |   2
```

Comment: please explain with sample output

Comment: for example if the voucherType=2 and ProductID=1 then Sum all the value in StockIn with same ProductID and also same in StockIn then find which value is greater StockIn or StockOUT

Comment: Sample data *and* desired results can help convey what you really want to do.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: hi this query is not working that give wrong result...... DECLARE @sum int=35; DECLARE @a int DECLARE @b int set @a=1 set @b=2 SELECT product_id , COUNT(stock_in) as Count_stockIn , COUNT(stock_out) as Count_stockOut , SUM(stock_in) as Sum_stockIn , SUM(stock_out)+@sum as Sum_stockOut , CASE WHEN SUM (stock_in) >= SUM (stock_out) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS IsInGreater From Stock Group By product_id Having product_id = 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT productId
    , voucherType
    , COUNT(stockIn) as Count_stockIn
    , SUM(stockIn) as Sum_stockIn
    , COUNT(stockOut) as Count_stockOut
    , CASE WHEN SUM(stockIn) > SUM(stockOut) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS IsInGreater
From Table
Group By productId, voucherType
Having productId = voucherType And IsInGreater = 'True'
```

This is kind of what you want? (your question is seriously unclear)

Comment: SELECT productId
   
    , COUNT(stockIn) as Count_stockIn
    , SUM(stockIn) as Sum_stockIn
    , COUNT(stockOut) as Count_stockOut
 , SUM(stockOut) as Sum_stockOut
    , CASE WHEN SUM(stockIn) >= SUM(stockOut) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS IsInGreater
From Stock
Group By productId
Having productId = 1 this is working for me i just want to also add the other value in sum(stockout) that will come on run time.thanks advance

Comment: @ImranBashir perfect :) glad to have helped. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it's solved your question

Comment: can u plz tell me how i can also add the value in sum(stockout) the value come as parameter

Comment: What like    DECLARE SumParam INT = 2;  ...... then in the select statement do: SUM(stockOut) + SumParam, ...... (Put an "at" symbol in front of the parameter names)

Comment: hi this query is not working that give wrong result...... DECLARE @sum int=35;
  DECLARE @a int
  DECLARE @b int
  set @a=1
  set @b=2

   SELECT product_id
   
    , COUNT(stock_in) as Count_stockIn
 , COUNT(stock_out) as Count_stockOut
    , SUM(stock_in) as Sum_stockIn
 , SUM(stock_out)+@sum as Sum_stockOut
    , CASE WHEN SUM (stock_in) >= SUM (stock_out) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS IsInGreater
From Stock
Group By product_id
Having product_id = 25

Comment: that give the wrong ans when the StockIn=10 and StockOut=9 then that give true and when the stockOut=15 and StockIn=10 then that also give the true ...

Comment: @ImranBashir did you also put the "+ @sum" in the CASE statemement?

Comment: no before case  , COUNT(stock_in) as Count_stockIn
 , COUNT(stock_out) as Count_stockOut
    , SUM(stock_in) as Sum_stockIn
 , SUM(stock_out)+@sum  as Sum_stockOut
    , 
 CASE

Comment: Try also adding it to the CASE statement. Eg CASE WHEN SUM(stock_in) >= (SUM(stock_out) + @sum) THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END

Comment: @ImranBashir did you make sure to use the brackets?

Comment: where i can upload the image that explain everything or give me a plz ur id

Comment: WHEN SUM(stock_in) > (SUM(stock_out)+@sum)THEN when i try this then @sum value does not add in stock_out

Comment: It says true because Sum(StockIn) = 9 and Sum(StockOut) = 7.  9 > 7 so it says true.  You have to use SUM(StockIn) >= (SUM(StockOut) + @Sum)

Comment: when i try this that did not add the sum value http://imgur.com/a/jVivf

Comment: @ImranBashir Yeah that makes the CASE part right. You just need to add the +@Sum back to the other field. You can use sum more then once

Comment: You need use SUM(StockOut)+ @sum AS Sum_StockOut, CASE WHEN SUM(StockIn) >= (SUM(StockOut) +@Sum) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END.  Notice I can use "At"Sum more then once

Comment: @ImranBashir post it as another question

Comment: i want to convert this query into store procedure how i can do this

Comment: It's simple:    CREATE PROC sp_Stocks @Sum INT AS   <Then put in the query here>

Comment: and i want to return the value to application true or false how i can do this

Comment: @ImranBashir only have the CASE in the select list

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/k63qS help me that not give me the result how i can use case here that return  @returncode=1 when the case is true

Comment: Get rid of all the other fields being selected or assign them to a variable like @IsGreater is

Comment: thank u man working fine now ...good man  can i add u in my fb